# SVG Google marker not working in Firefox

Tags: google-maps, firefox, svg, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Random SVG bug, I've spent the last hour trying to figure out why my SVG icon isn't working with Google Markers within Firefox.

I'm using the following snippet to get and resize the SVG.

Any and all advice would be appreciated, thank you.

```
  url: 'svg/icon_inactive.svg',
  size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple fix, I just needed to add a height and width to the SVG - schoolboy error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="enable-background:new 0 0 20 20;" xml:space="preserve" height="30px" width="30px">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{opacity:0.9;fill:#ED1D7F;}
</style>
<g>
    <circle class="st0" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/>
</g>
</svg>
```